# I can't figure out Unity / Blender / makehuman root motion

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender-2.61, makehuman

I have tried every single variation and permutation that I can think of.

I start at make human while I'm prototyping because it's fast. I then take it to Blender where I apply a bvh file.

I adjust the graph editor because the bvh files never get it quite right. Then I import into Unity.

I think the root node would be [character/master/root]. I set the root position x/y baked. I have set the rig's root to the above.

My character either jumps back at loop, which I know means wrong root node, but when he doesn't do that there is no forward movement whatsoever.

Unless I click is kinematic which removes the interaction with physics.

When iskinematic is clicked it moves like I want it to, but you know that isn't good for physics. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution i had not seen yet and i went back to make human and imported a new unity rig from https://forum.unity.com/threads/makehuman-and-unity.617311/

and exported to blender using the unity export...

then i exported to unity and made a humanoid animation it seems to be working better